# Scalling font size in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms, label

I am working with xamarin forms and facing problems with the layout. Now, with the fontsize..
I have two labels and one of them is Micro. I need that the other get the size of the Micro label / 2 as its size...I am reading about relative layout, but I don't know if it's the best way to do that...does someone have any idea to help me?
This is my labels:

```
   <StackLayout Spacing="0">
        <Label x:Name="menu_lbl_promocoes" Text="0000" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{Binding labelsfont}"/>
        <Label x:Name="menu_lbl_disponiveis" Text="Disponíveis" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small" Style="{Binding labelsfont}"/>
   </StackLayout>

       </StackLayout> //yeah, there is another stacklayout 

       <Label Text="Promoções" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{Binding labelsfont}"/>
```

I need the second label get the half size of the third (which has a micro size)...

Comment: Micro is the smallest readable fontsize, doing the size of this in half you won't be able to read it properly, you sure you want it like that?

Comment: the problem is:
In my layout on ios the micro size is big kkkk The large is very big...then, the size that xamarin gives to me is not working well...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply extend `Label` to have two bindable properties - `FontSizeFactor` and `NamedFontSize` - and have them calculate the font size for you:

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeFactorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
        "FontSizeFactor", typeof(double), typeof(MyLabel),
        defaultValue: 1.0, propertyChanged: OnFontSizeFactorChanged);

    public double FontSizeFactor
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeFactorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontSizeFactorProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnFontSizeFactorChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((MyLabel)bindable).OnFontSizeChangedImpl();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty NamedFontSizeProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
        "NamedFontSize", typeof(NamedSize), typeof(MyLabel),
        defaultValue: NamedSize.Small, propertyChanged: OnNamedFontSizeChanged);

    public NamedSize NamedFontSize
    {
        get { return (NamedSize)GetValue(NamedFontSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NamedFontSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnNamedFontSizeChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((MyLabel)bindable).OnFontSizeChangedImpl();
    }

    protected virtual void OnFontSizeChangedImpl()
    {
        if (this.FontSizeFactor != 1)
            this.FontSize = (this.FontSizeFactor * Device.GetNamedSize(NamedFontSize, typeof(Label)));
    }
}
```

**Sample Usage:**

```
    <Label FontSize="Large" Text="Large Size" />
    <local:MyLabel NamedFontSize="Large" FontSizeFactor="0.9" Text="90% Large Size" />

    <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="Medium Size" />
    <local:MyLabel NamedFontSize="Medium" FontSizeFactor="0.75" Text="75% Medium Size" />

    <Label FontSize="Micro" Text="Micro Size" />
    <local:MyLabel NamedFontSize="Micro" FontSizeFactor="0.5" Text="50% Micro Size" />
```

[image: ios screenshot]

[image: android screenshot]

Comment: this attribute FontSizeFactor comes with this script, right?
I will try that and tell u

Comment: I am getting this "'local' is an undeclared prefix.". I need to put somenthing in xaml top, dont I?

Comment: Yes you need to declare the namespace of MyLabel - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/namespaces/#Declaring_Namespaces_for_Types

Comment: but it seems dont working for android...i dont know why

Comment: I tested this - it worked fine; please see updated answer. If size difference is an issue - then you need to use OnPlatform to specify different values for each platform

Answer (score 3):

So ima give an example on how to do it:
We got 2 labels.
**First one with micro**

```
 <Label  x:Name="statuslabel" FontSize="Micro" Text="Filter status:" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="100" />
```

**Second one without size**

Than in the codein the constructur, at the last line you write:

```
    typelabel.FontSize = statuslabel.FontSize / 2;
```

the result:
[image: result]